# NIFI - Using one ReplaceText Processor how to add brackets at the beginning and end of each line

Tags: json, apache-nifi, parquet, processor, apache-kudu

I have the following 10000 rows of log file every 5 seconds.

```
log_datetime1 host_name1 log_message1
log_datetime2 host_name2 log_message2
log_datetime3 host_name3 log_message3
```

I want to send them to kudu or parquet table as the following `JSON`

```
{"cureent_datetime":"datetime", "log_data":"log_datetime1 host_name1 log_message1"}
{"cureent_datetime":"datetime", "log_data":"log_datetime2 host_name2 log_message2"}
{"cureent_datetime":"datetime", "log_data":"log_datetime3 host_name3 log_message3"}
```

Currently I'm using `Two ReplaceText Processors`. One to add the
`{"cureent_datetime":"datetime", "log_data":"` at the beginning of each line of 10000 rows log file and the second one to add `"}` at the end of each line.

Was wondering if I could do the both step in `one ReplaceText proecssor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the search pattern `(.+)(?=\n)` and the replacement pattern `{"current_datetime":"datetime", "log_data":"$1"}` will result in the desired output. The search pattern looks for text which is followed by a newline, and the replacement includes the capture group inside the templated JSON structure.

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you @Andy !